# my sql recursive relationship update cascade

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

```
create table employee(emp_id int primary key ,emp_name char(9),
spouse_id int,foreign key(spouse_id)references employee (emp_id)
on delete cascade set null on update cascade);
```

hi friends

when i delete an data it give impact on related  data.
but when i tried to update it, it give error cant change parent data.
please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 2):

remove cascade

```
on delete set null
```

but regarding edit.. it works fine in my example..

Maybe this can help you from Mysql reference:

> Deviation from SQL standards: If ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL
>   recurses to update the same table it
>   has previously updated during the
>   cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. This
>   means that you cannot use
>   self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or
>   ON UPDATE SET NULL operations. This is
>   to prevent infinite loops resulting
>   from cascaded updates. A
>   self-referential ON DELETE SET NULL,
>   on the other hand, is possible, as is
>   a self-referential ON DELETE CASCADE.
>   Cascading operations may not be nested
>   more than 15 levels deep.